# Tap issue with curve views in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, xcode11, bezier

I have a requirement to create a view that has a top and bottom view merged where the top view needs to have a curve at the bottom and both the top and bottom view performs different actions on tap. I was able to create this view as below

[image]

This is the screenshot of my storyboard constraints

[image]

This is my curve view class

```
class CurveView: UIView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.createBottomCurve()
    }

    private func createBottomCurve() {
        let offset: CGFloat = self.frame.width / 1.2
        let bounds: CGRect = self.bounds
        let rectBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height / 2)
        let rectPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rectBounds)
        let ovalBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x - offset / 2, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width + offset, height: bounds.size.height)
        let ovalPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: ovalBounds)
        rectPath.append(ovalPath)
        let maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = bounds
        maskLayer.path = rectPath.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```

And this is the implementation in viewcontroller class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var greenCurveView: CurveView!
    @IBOutlet weak var yellowView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let greenViewTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGreenViewTap(_:)))
        greenViewTap.delegate = self
        greenCurveView.addGestureRecognizer(greenViewTap)
        let yellowViewTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleYellowTap(_:)))
        yellowViewTap.delegate = self
        yellowView.addGestureRecognizer(yellowViewTap)
    }

    @objc func handleGreenViewTap(_ pan: UITapGestureRecognizer ){
        print("Green View is tapped")
    }

    @objc func handleYellowTap(_ pan: UITapGestureRecognizer ){
        print("Yellow View is tapped")
    }

}
```

This works fine except in the scenario where we tap yellow view in the highlighted rectangle area in red in the below image. In the below image, if I click on the yellow area in rectangle it takes the tap of green view which makes sense since the yellow view is behind green view. So, how do I determine the yellow area tap in this region? Any help is appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to instruct `CurveView` where it can be tapped, in this case within its own path:

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
       return rectPath.contains(point)
}
```

So overall your `CurveView` could look like this:

```
class CurveView: UIView {

    var rectPath = UIBezierPath()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.createBottomCurve()
    }

    private func createBottomCurve() {
        let offset: CGFloat = self.frame.width / 1.2
        let bounds: CGRect = self.bounds
        let rectBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height / 2)
        rectPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rectBounds)
        let ovalBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x - offset / 2, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width + offset, height: bounds.size.height)
        let ovalPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: ovalBounds)
        rectPath.append(ovalPath)
        let maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = bounds
        maskLayer.path = rectPath.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
           return rectPath.contains(point)
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Wow! Simple and quick answer.